# How do I add a column to my dataframe containing means between years from another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes in Python, one containing information on cars and another containing information on fuel prices (gasoline and diesel). Examples of the dataframes are as follows.

**cars**

```
   regNo  regYear inspectionYear fuelType
0  AB1234 2008    2012           Gasoline
1  CD2345 2009    2011           Diesel
2  LD9876 2010    2013           Diesel
```

**fuelPrice**

```
year fuelType price
2008 Gasoline 12.13
2009 Gasoline 19.52
2010 Gasoline 13.32
2011 Gasoline 13.54
2012 Gasoline 16.23
2013 Gasoline 11.34
2008 Diesel   9.43
2009 Diesel   9.37
2010 Diesel   9.89
2011 Diesel   10.04
2012 Diesel   8.42
2013 Diesel   9.21
```

What I attempt to do is to add a column to **cars** which is the average price of the relevant fuelType between *regYear* and *inspectionYear*. So I wish to end up with something like this:

**cars_newCol**

```
   regNo  regYear inspectionYear fuelType fuelPrice
0  AB1234 2008    2012           Gasoline 14.95
1  CD2345 2009    2011           Diesel   9.77
2  LD9876 2010    2013           Diesel   9.39
```

That is, the first row is the average of fuel prices from **fuelPrice** for *Gasoline* between years 2008 and 2012.

I have tried various solutions, but the one I feel is closest to something is probably:

```
cars['fuelPrice'] = fuel_prices.loc[(fuel_prices['year']>=cars['regYear']) & 
                                    (fuel_prices['year']<=cars['inspectionYear']) &
                                    (fuel_prices['fuelType']==cars['fuelType']),
                                    'price'].mean()
```

However, the output isn't as expected. The dataframe is quite large (~7 mio. rows), thus I dont fancy doing it in a for-loop, unless someone thinks this could be efficient.

Thank you in advance - much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `merge`, then filter the rows and groupby:

```
(cars.merge(fuelPrice, on='fuelType')
     .query('regYear<= year <= inspectionYear')
     .groupby(cars.columns.to_list(), as_index=False)['price'].mean()
)
```

Output:

```
    regNo  regYear  inspectionYear  fuelType      price
0  AB1234     2008            2012  Gasoline  14.948000
1  CD2345     2009            2011    Diesel   9.766667
2  LD9876     2010            2013    Diesel   9.390000
```